# Voice typing in Android for a disabled person with very limited hand function

Tags: voice-recognition, external-keyboard, accessibility

I have a close friend who is suffering from a neurological disorder similar to [ALS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amyotrophic_lateral_sclerosis) (Lou Gehrig's disease).  Over the last year his arms, hands and fingers have weakened greatly to the point where he can no longer type or hold a pen.  He is a writer.  As yet we cannot afford expensive assistive technologies or a full time assistant, so I have been trying to use an Android tablet to help him write via Voice Typing.

He writes in Hindi.

We have done some experiments combining the tablet with an external keyboard that he keeps on a tray (with the tablet on a desk), since lifting his hand up to tap on the screen or to hold the tablet tires him out quickly.  The goal of our experiments is to reduce the need to tap the screen to an absolute minimum.  Using this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en) we have set up a key on the keyboard to start voice typing, so he no longer has to tap to start it.    However, I have some questions:

- Voice typing will sometimes stop and ask you to tap the microphone icon to start it again.  As far as I can see this seems random but happens every one or two minutes.  The external keyboard key has no effect on this and he has to lift his hand to tap the microphone icon.  Why does this happen?  Is there a way this can be reduced?  Alternatively, is there some other method that will allow a tap on a key to restart voice typing without needing to tap the screen?
- Are there any guides to how to speak most effectively for dictation to Voice Typing (e.g. which is best - full sentences at a slow speed, full sentences at a normal speed, a few words at a time, or some other combination?)?
- At times voice typing will seem to "jam" and simply stop writing anything - even though the microphone icon is red and it seems to be hearing.  After a minute it may start to write a lot, or it may just seem to hang, and restarting it requires tapping it once to stop it and then again to start it.  The tablet is an old machine (3 years old) that is extremely low end - Android 4.4. running on 1 GB RAM.  Is this a result of the low end nature of the tablet?
- Is there a way to allow external keyboard typing in a language other than English (i.e. similar to the Gboard's phonetic entry for other languages)? He can use this for a few corrections to the frequent mistakes that Voice Typing makes (we'll ask someone else to clean up the final text, however).

I hope there are ways around these things - it is crushing to watch a major literary writer lose his ability to write.... If I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely and you all have suggestions on better methods, that would also be great.